# Flutter Firestore Stream builder "A value of type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to a variable"

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve data from my Firestore database via a Streambuilder. The issue I have comes from an error from the following error when I add my doc(uid) into my _usersStream:

```
A value of type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>'.
```

I was wondering how to how to rectify this error. Here is my code:

```
class _UserProfileScreenState extends State<UserProfileScreen> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("");
        }

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: ProfileAppBar(),
          body: ListView(
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data =
                  document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(data['username']),
                subtitle: Text(data['displayName']),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is some issue when you define `_userStream`

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).snapshots();
```

`_userStream` is a value of type `Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>`

`_userStream` should be like this.

```
final Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).snapshots();
```

it is better to use `FutureBuilder`

```
class GetUserName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;

  GetUserName(this.documentId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text("Full Name: ${data['full_name']} ${data['last_name']}");
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Please check this [guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/)

Comment: I'm aware of FutureBuilder but my data ui needs to be updated in a continuous matter

Comment: you can also use `StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>`